# Is `flutter build web` supposed to output a file called flutter.js? Because it does not by me :(

Tags: flutter

In Flutter web apps, there is a reference to a script called `flutter.js` but it is not outputed by the build. Is it normal? It actually gives a 404 error in one of my apps :(.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I got confused between `/web` and `/build/web`.

Comment: How did you mix them ?

Comment: I meant I confused them

Comment: I don't understand what it means to have "confused" them. I don't see where you've used either '/web' or '/build/web' and as such this answer doesn't give me any actionable advice on how to fix my issue

Answer (score 1):

After some frustration and some investigation...

In:
[image]

Change (IF app is not in root of website):
[image]

**So, href value should be the path to YOUR Flutter app with "/" as start and end in value**.

Enjoy!

Comment: Can you please give some context to your <base href>-value? I struggle with exactly the same issue and I wonder what you mean if you say "...should be the path to YOUR Flutter app..." - where does the path start, where does it end?

Comment: Well, my site has following url: https://jernberg.org/sandbox/flutter/
So, compare it to the value: "/sandbox/flutter/". Hope it helps!

Comment: Man. Why is this not in the basic flutter docs on deploying a web app.