# Flutter Web - Getting flutter_ is not defined after publishing github pages

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web, github-pages

I just build a flutter web project. I hosted it on github pages. After successfully from creating repository to deploying project I am getting this following error...

```
(index):46 Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined
```

I don't understand why is this happening. I tried `flutter clean`.

I searched for the solution. but many people suggested that run `flutter clean` command but it made no effect on the project.

Here is my code code for web build.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="code_snippets">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

  <title>code_snippets</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function (appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined` is may caused by wrong deployed folder.

you have to delpoy `web` directory insted of `build/web`

here some reference from github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107448#issuecomment-1181591460

or you may try this solution :

[Is `Flutter build web` supposed to output a file called flutter.js? Because it does not by me :(](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73070958/12838877)